# Bind failed with error code : 10048

Tags: sockets, winsock

I'm starting to program sockets in C on windows, with a simple example in order to learn how to use sockets in client and server applications.

This is my server code

```
#if defined WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#else
#define closesocket closeter 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arp /a inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for atoi()
#define PROTOPORT 8080 // default protocol port number
#define QLEN 6 // size of request queue

void ErrorHandler(char *errorMessage) {
    printf(errorMessage);
 }
void ClearWinSock() {
 #if defined WIN32
   WSACleanup();
 #endif
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int port;

    if (argc > 1) {
       port = atoi(argv[1]);
    } else
       port = PROTOPORT; // use default port number

    if (port < 0) {
       printf("bad port number %s \n", argv[1]);
       return 0;
    }

    #if defined WIN32 // initialize Winsock
      WSADATA wsaData;
      int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
      if (iResult != 0) {
         ErrorHandler("Error at WSAStartup()\n");
         return 0;
      }
    #endif

    int MySocket;
    MySocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (MySocket < 0) {
       ErrorHandler("socket creation failed.\n");
       ClearWinSock();
       return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sad;
    memset(&sad, 0, sizeof(sad)); // ensures that extra bytes contain 0
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sad.sin_port = htons(port); 

    if (bind(MySocket, (struct sockaddr*) &sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {
       printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(MySocket);
       ClearWinSock();
       return 0;
    }



    if (listen (MySocket, QLEN) < 0) {
       ErrorHandler("listen() failed.\n");
       closesocket(MySocket);
       ClearWinSock();
       return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in cad; // structure for the client address
    int clientSocket; // socket descriptor for the client
    int clientLen; // the size of the client address
    printf("Waiting for a client to connect...");

    while (1) { 
          clientLen = sizeof(cad); // set the size of the client address
          if ((clientSocket = accept(MySocket, (struct sockaddr *)&cad,
           &clientLen)) < 0) {
               ErrorHandler("accept() filed.\n");

               closesocket(MySocket);
               ClearWinSock();
               return 0;
           }
          printf("Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(cad.sin_addr));
       }
}// end of main
```

When i run it the console diplays this message:
Bind failed with error code : 10048
which means that the function bind returned a nonzero value, so an error occurred, the 10048 error. I know that this error means that the spicified port is already being used by an other application, so i tried to change the port number several times, but it still displays me the same error.
Thanks for help!!!

Comment: So they were all in use. Try some more.

Comment: i tried again but nothing changed... can you tell me a port number that i can use? i tried with 5193 5194 8888 8080